# My gsub is not working for my string, why?

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

this is my string:

```
x <- "NINSGSMN019VLKM6NINSGSMN05ZISGPBNINSGSMN04K36312NINSGSMN07AQ74H6NINSGSMN08LVCE18NINSGMDN0E57CIF6"
```

I want to change it to

```
"NINSGSMN019VLKM6"
"NINSGSMN05ZISGPB" 
"NINSGSMN04K36312"
"NINSGSMN07AQ74H6"
"NINSGSMN08LVCE18"
"NINSGMDN0E57CIF6"
```

so i was intending to use gsub to replace 'NINGSG' with ' NINGSG' and then use strsplit to split it by the spacebar. However I can't even do the sub.

`x <- gsub("NINGSG", " NINGSG", x, ignore.case = TRUE)` just returns me the exact same input

Comment: Check your pattern. You need to use "NINSGS", not ""NINGSG" ..

Comment: oh. my. gosh. i have been so confused for the past hour T^T thank you so much @r.user.05apr